# What is the equivalent of SQL Profiler in Oracle?

Tags: oracle

I am new to Oracle DB. I have used SQL Management Studio extensively. I have used SQL profiler. SQL profiler lists all the queries executed whenever there is a database call. I need similar option in Oracle.

Comment: StackOverflow is about helping people fix their existing code. Requests for tool recommendations, tutorials, research,  libraries, and code are off-topic.  ***Please*** read  http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask , http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask ,  http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve  and take the [tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) before posting more Qs here. Good luck.

Comment: I will take care of your points in future. Thank you for guiding me.

Answer (score 0):

There is probably no direct equivalent. So a few things.

1. It's probably more effective to state what you are trying to achieve, rather that asking for a specific tool or piece of functionality
2. For System wide monitoring, there is Enterprise Manager (EM) and EM Express.

   - EM gives you access to the Automatic Workload Repository (AWR), which can provide an overall system report
   - For SQL specific monitoring EM gives you access to SQL*Monitor

Both AWR and SQL*Monitor can be accessed outside of EM too.

Comment: You might want to note which of those utilities is an extra cost option within Oracle.

Comment: @MT0 I've no idea :)

Comment: There are some queries/ stored procedures executed in soap server.Soap server is a black box for me. So I don't know what are the queries being executed. So in SQL management studio, in such scenario, I can run SQL profile while running my application. It lists all the queries, executed by the application,at the same time. I need the similar functionality/ code, which can give me the all the executed queries while I run my application.

Comment: @Sunita Well the next question is what will you do with a list of every query? I would probably start by generating an AWR report. By default, snapshots are taken every hour. But you can manually take a snapshot and the start and end of each run and generate an AWR report for that pair of snapshots.

Comment: I do not know which table is used to get me the data. There are huge list of tables present. So if I can identify the table, I can see the data.

Comment: @Sunita An AWR will report will certainly give you the "expensive" queries and from that you'll probably be able to determine the tables in question.